# "Three pair" vs. "three pairs"

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is more grammatically correct: "three pairs of shoes" or "three pair of shoes"?

Comment: In 1800, "three pair" would have been correct. Today, "three pairs" is correct. See [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+pair%2F+three+pairs%2Cthree+pair+of%2Fthree+pairs+of&year_start=1750&year_end=1950&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: I think the pair form for plural is still often used when playing cards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on who you ask. From the *[Columbia Guide to Standard American English](http://books.google.com/books?id=L2ChiO2yEZ0C&pg=PA315&dq=%22three%20pair%20of%20shoes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5sIoUpfXBKmwsASy1oDwBQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22three%20pair%20of%20shoes%22&f=false)* by K.G. Wilson:

> Some commentators object to locutions such as *three pair of shoes*, arguing that the modifying number should force *pair* to be *pairs*. But at least in most Conversational and Informal use, *three pair* and *four pair* are appropriate.

[Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20pair%20of%20shoes,five%20pairs%20of%20shoes,four%20pair%20of%20pants,four%20pairs%20of%20pants&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) show that both are in use, although *three pairs* is heavily favored. To me, *three pair of shoes* has an old-fashioned ring to it, but I wouldn't correct you if you said it.

Comment: +1, but I think for someone learning English, they should just stick with "three pairs". "Three pair" is not suitable for everyday normal use.

Comment: I agree. However, I think it's worth explaining here nonetheless. The O.P. didn't ask "Which one should I use?" but rather "Which is correct?" If we say that one of them is _wrong_, then what does that do to our credibility when a non-native [encounters the lesser-used form](https://www.google.com/#q=%22three+pair+of+pants%22)?

Comment: Brilliant answer! +1. I agree with you both :) And I think the last paragraph of the answer is more than sufficient to point non-native speakers toward using the more common form :)

Comment: I also suspect this could be very regional. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that there are some parts of the U.S. where "three pair of pants" sounds decidedly off, yet that wording may sound quite normal in others.

Comment: I grew up in the US Midwest and later lived in the US South for a time, and "three pair" is very commonly used in both regions.  It has a distinctly unsophisticated sound to my ear.  I would stick to "three pairs" unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As you're describing more than one pair of shoes, you should use the plural form of the noun:

> Three pairs of shoes.

Though it's worth noting that if you're describing one pair, this would be correct:

> One pair of shoes.

As even though there are multiple shoes involved, there's still just a singular pair.

Some nouns have the same form in both the singular and the plural though. This is something you'll need to learn as you come across the particular words.

> Why have one sheep when you can have three sheep?